# Get the data for the same hive query in chunks from hive

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I have a table with million of records. I want to execute a hive query, and want to return the result set in chunks to the client. Like say on the first client request for fetch results, I want to return the first 1000 records, then on subsequent requests the next 1000 records and so on.
One way is, I fetch the complete result set while executing hive query and save it and iterate the result set as per the request from the client. But if my result set is very huge then it can creating out of memory issues while saving the complete result set in memory.

**Is it possible to get the data for the same hive query in chunks from hive?** As per my exploration, I found that hive does not have support for pagination and also every time I cannot execute the query using limit clause in hive, as the documentation of hive says that the limit clause picks the records randomly.

I am using JDBC for hive query execution. **Is there any solution provided in JDBC that can work with hive?**
**Or Is there any other approach to address this use case?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The below is just an alternative approach:

Make your hive table bucketed and use the column or cloumns which are unique and has values in a range as the cluster by fields. Since you use cluster by your data would be sorted globally and distributed so you could always do the select query with these columns as your filter condition.

The above is just a suggestion.Hope it helps